# Parameters Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Hey guys i have a problem returning certain file with the Google Drive API.

```
    function retrieve_all_files($service,$parameters) {

    $result = array();
    $pageToken = NULL;

    do {
        try {
            $parameters = array();

            if ($pageToken) {
                $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
            }
            $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

            $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
            $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
            $pageToken = NULL;

        }
    } while ($pageToken);

    return $result;

}

$format = DateTime::RFC3339;
$date = new DateTime('now');
$date->modify('-3 days');
$date_str = $date->format($format);

$parameters = array('q' => "trashed = false and modifiedDate < '$date_str'");

echo count(retrieve_all_files($service, $parameters));
```

For some reason the parameter option returns all the files and not the ones according to the specific criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code always replaces the value of the parameters passed to retrieve_all_files with an empty array:

```
...
$parameters = array();
...
```

That's the reason why your parameters are being ignored.

Comment: This is embarassing, must of been really tired. ;)